# implement my own java.nio for socket server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

Ive been reading for the past few days about the difference between io and nio when building a java socket server. for my use i need a server which can run lots of connections and ion supposed to do the trick.
My only fear is that it a bit slower and a bit harder to implement instead of running a thread for each connection. so i thought why dont i use the same easiness of threads and the logic of java.nio and build a server has a thread which checks all the open connection and when ever there is a new event, it will open a new thread for handing it.  i think in that way im enjoying both of the worlds... what do u suggest?

Comment: There are multiple high performance nio libraries out there like netty and grizzly which should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NIO almost entirely relies on JNI, so if you want to implement it again, you'll actually have to write loads of C/++ and OS API interface code.

I think the existing Java implementations are already quite good. For example, the Selector class wraps the system call for waiting on multiple file descriptors. There's hardly anything you can do to improve the efficiency of that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't understand the point of NIO, which is to only use one thread. It is certainly complex and it is arguable whether you have any need for it at all below 1000 clients, probably 10,000, possibly even 100,000. I would implement your server with java.net to get it running and save java.nio for phase 2 if you ever get there and prove to yourself that you really need it.

**EDIT:** I would certainly forget this concept of rolling your own. You're wildly underestimating the task (It took Sun 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2 before it really worked properly), and you seem to be aiming to get the worst of both worlds. You won't be able to get any more out of it than Sun did with java.nio, as there isn't any more. Arguably a bit less ;-)

Comment: First its a good idea. second i can do all in one thread. isnt that what nio does? Run a new thread for each tesk and cloae it after?

Comment: @AsafNevo You need a separate thread per connection with java.net.